# Resources for using Java hashtables? Mountain of difficulties. Cannot use Hashmaps

Tags: java, hashtable

Afternoon, I'm trying to implement a hashtable in Java, using K mod 13 as the hash function. **Does anyone know of any resources to learn about hashtables?** I've been searching on Google, and several forums for hours (*maybe I'm doing it wrong*).

I received an incredibly abstract lesson on Hashtables on Friday, describing collisions, overflow etc. but absolutely NOTHING on implementation. Since the assignment is on Hashtables, I cannot use Hashmaps, as several people have reccommended, and condemned me for not doing.

So far, this is all I can come up with as sad as it may be.

```
private Hashtable <String, String> ht = new Hashtable <String,String>(20);
```

In order to solve the problem I've been assigned, **I need to use a hashtable of integers, but Java isn't allowing this...do you know why?**

Both of the following code segments are invalid:

```
private Hashtable <Int, Int> ht = new Hashtable <Int, Int>(20);
private Hashtable <int, int> ht = new Hashtable <int, int>(20);
```

I'd greatly appreciate some assistance to steer me in the right direction, all attempts to seek assistance from colleagues has resulted in less than favourable outcomes.

I apologize for my lack of knowledge on the subject,
Thanks.

Comment: Try it with the `Integer` wrapper class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys and values of a Hashtable must be objects, not primitives.

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {
 private Hashtable <Integer, Integer> ht = new Hashtable <Integer, Integer>(20);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea where I can learn anything else about hashtables besides the Java API? The only information I can find online is concerning hashmaps.

Comment: O'Reilly press has a lot of their info online. their book Java in a Nutshell back in the late 80's/early 90's was what got me started.